# JPQL запрос где Entity, которую ищем - параметр. Как лучше написать?

Tags: jpa, persistance, hibernate, java

```
public <T> T getSingleEntityByParameter(Class entityClass, String fieldName, Object parameter) {
    TypedQuery<T> query = PersistenceHelper.getQuery("from " + entityClass.getName() + " s where s." + fieldName + "=:param", entityClass);
    query.setParameter("param", parameter);
    query.setMaxResults(1);
    List<T> entities = query.getResultList();
    if (!entities.isEmpty()) {
        return entities.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Можно написать лучше?

Comment: можно без критериев =)

Comment: ну это и есть без критериев (правда не понимаю почему их все так не любят). мне же тут не нравится то как я задаю класс, и то как надо выбирать один результат из возвращаемого листа. а getSingleResult(), как известно, кидает разные exceptions..